# Resetting the DB after each test run

Tags: testing, persistence, automated-tests, hsqldb, h2

I have following problem:

I have a DB pre-filled with lot of test data. After each test run I would like to throw away changes made by the test procedure. I already tried to do this with an embedded H2 DB. I would just overwrite the DB files with the original ones and the problem would be solved. But another problem emerged: H2 doesn't support multi-threading without running as a server.

After that I looked at HSQLDB. If I understand it correctly, if it is used as normal file DB (not in-memory) it will still load the contents of the DB into the memory and persist the changed to disk after some time.

Is there any possibility to just read the file DB into memory, use it there and throw away any changes at the end? This would be perfect. A solution using rollbacks would be great too.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Why is the lack of multi-threading support an issue?

Comment: Because the application relies heavily multi-threading and won't work without it. Sometimes more than 20 threads are accessing the DB simultaneously. It would be still OK if it works slow in tests, but it should work.

Comment: OK but no matter what DB solution you pick, all the threads will have to wait as the DB gets "restored" at the end of the test run, right?

Comment: That is not a problem, CI would quit the application, do a rollback and start the application one more time for further tests.

Comment: Right, so it's not really an issue for resetting the DB, just for your application in general. I was confused about that.

Comment: Actually, H2 does support multi-threading when used in all modes (including embedded mode, in-memory mode and so on). You just need to append `;MULTI_THREADED=TRUE` to the database URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the H2 database:

- To load a database from script, [append `;INIT=runscript from '~/create.sql'` to the database URL](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection). You could also load the script from a resource in the classpath; for this replace `~/create.sql` with [`classpath:/com/acme/init/create.sql`](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system). You can use that in combination of an in-memory database (`jdbc:h2:mem:test;...`) if you are not interested about the changes.
- To use the H2 database in multi-threaded mode, [append `;MULTI_THREADED=1` to the database URL](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_multi_threaded). This applies to all modes (in-memory, embedded, client/server).

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB has an option for this usage.

After creating the test database, perform SHUTDOWN. You will have a .properties and .script files. In the .properties file add this line:

```
files_readonly=true
```

Then use this database for the tests. No rollback or any special action will be necessary when the app exits.

Alternatively, append this to your test application's connection URL, `;files_readonly=true`

See this Chapter of the Guide:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_db_file_mem

For multi-threaded application testing, the database transaction model is usually MVCC, which you set in the original database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't try it out, because we prefer H2 and with the answer provided by Thomas it works really well.